# Trouble with Python If Statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm working through a lesson and I'm stuck.  Since I'm new with Python, it's hard to figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
#Write your two "if" statements below!

def true_function():
    if                #Fill in your `if` statement here!
        return        #Make sure this function returns `True`

def false_function():
    if                #Fill in your `if` statement here!
        return        #Make sure this function returns `False`
```

This is my proposed solution, which gives me an error;

```
#Write your two "if" statements below!

    def true_function():
        if  2 + 2 == 4:           #Fill in your `if` statement here!
            return 'True'   #Make sure this function returns `True`

    def false_function():
        if  2 + 2 == 5:           #Fill in your `if` statement here!
            return 'False' #Make sure this function returns `False`
```

Can someone help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please post the _full traceback_ of the error.

Comment: This isn't immediately relevant to the issues you're having, but in my opinion this lesson is pretty silly. There's almost never a good reason to write a function that will have a guaranteed result that you know in advance. Similarly, if you know the answer you want to return, you don't need an `if` statement to get there!

Comment: I can't really tell since I'm a newbie.  It's on Codecademy and I guess the intention is to demonstrate how the structure works mechanically.  To that end, I think it succeeds.  Both if statements must be true in order for their respective outputs to be spit out.  If they're not, they're ignored.

Answer (score 5):

`True` and `False` are objects (or variables, or constants, or soft-keywords, or whatever you want to call them).  They aren't strings.

```
return True
```

Your second function is also using a false condition, so the contents of the `if` block will never run.  It'll drop off the end and return `None` instead.

Comment: keep in mind that because your second `if` condition is false, it'll never run...

Comment: Hi Kimomaru, in case you find an answer useful, kindly [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the tick mark on the left side of the answer :)